# Function returning Object vs Object()

Tags: vb.net, syntax, overloading

What is the difference (if any) between

```
Protected Function MyFunction() As Object()
```

and

```
Protected Function MyFunction() As Object
```

Visual Studio says the following, so I assume there must be a difference.

> [the moethods] cannot overload each other because they differ only by
>   return types.

Sorry if I missed a duplicate, but I couldn't find anything online.

Comment: The first one returns an Array of Objects, the second a simple Object.

Comment: If it is said by Visual Studio, then probably you are using VB, not VBA (Visual Basic for Applications - Alt+F11 in Excel, PowerPoint, Word, Access).

Comment: As the error says they have only return types that vary......You have to have different types or number of arguments to overload.....The return type cannot be used to overload a function

Comment: @z32a7ul Thanks... being used to C# syntax was what threw me off. Could you post it as an answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned it in the comments:
The first one returns an Array of Objects, the second a simple Object.